# Play framework seems to be double posting my WS Async Post

Tags: java, playframework

I'm doing a long running post using WSAsync (i've tried using post()
and postAsync() with the same results)

What seems to be happening is that WS is doing the post with the
proper multipart content type, it waits a few ms then does the post
again without the content type (why it's doing it twice i've got no
idea), the service that it's calling the responds with an HTTP 415 and
play then errors out.  I'll post the Trace output from play and the
method doing the call.

### METHOD

```
public static void performBatchImport(AssetBatchImport batchImport){
    validation.valid(batchImport);
    if (validation.hasErrors()) {
            putAssetLookupValuesInContext();
            render("@add", batchImport);
    }
    FileParam fp = new FileParam(batchImport.import_file, "file");
    Promise<HttpResponse> fresponse =
WS.url(ApiUtils.getAssetBaseUri() + "batch-
import").setParameter("header_record_present",
batchImport.header_record_present)
                    .setParameter("account_id",
batchImport.account.id).mimeType("multipart/form-
data").files(fp).timeout("1h").postAsync();
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
            response = fresponse.get(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(response != null && RestUtils.isOk(response)){
            AssetImportBatch batch =
GsonFactory.getGson().fromJson(response.getString(),
AssetImportBatch.class);
            flash.put("batchId", batch.id);
            flash.keep();
            add(batch.id);
    }else if(RestUtils.isNotSupported(response)){
            //redirect
            flash.success("Your request is currently processing");
            add(null);
    }
    else{
            ApiUtils.processErrorResponse("batchImport", response,
validation);
            putAssetLookupValuesInContext();
            render("@add", batchImport);
    }
}
```

---

### TRACE

```
17:12:05,776 DEBUG ~
Using cached Channel [id: 0x00f02e1b, /127.0.0.1:50050 => localhost/
127.0.0.1:8080]
 for request
DefaultHttpRequest(chunked: false)
POST /our-product/api/assets/batch-import HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization: Bearer d3173239-3e94-4324-be4b-asdfasw452as
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: NING/1.0
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=JIbZxjblkj0oG0S02OWe47-
Gx_ZlUlNo9Ct
Content-Length: 145758

17:12:18,631 TRACE ~ 0 idle channels closed (times: 1st-loop=0, 2nd-
loop=0).

17:12:36,216 DEBUG ~ Channel Closed: [id: 0x00f02e1b, /
127.0.0.1:50050 :> localhost/127.0.0.1:8080] with attachment
NettyResponseFuture{currentRetry=0,
        isDone=false,
        isCancelled=false,
        asyncHandler=play.libs.ws.WSAsync$WSAsyncRequest$1@d5d62e,
        responseTimeoutInMs=3600000,
        nettyRequest=DefaultHttpRequest(chunked: false)
POST /our-product/api/assets/batch-import HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization: Bearer d3173239-3e94-4324-be4b-asdfasw452as
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: NING/1.0
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=JIbZxjblkj0oG0S02OWe47-
Gx_ZlUlNo9Ct
Content-Length: 145758,
        content=null,
        uri=http://localhost:8080/our-product/api/assets/batch-import,
        keepAlive=true,
        httpResponse=null,
        exEx=null,
        redirectCount=0,

reaperFuture=com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider
$ReaperFuture@e08014,
        inAuth=false,
        statusReceived=false,
        touch=1322691125777}
17:12:36,216 DEBUG ~ Trying to recover request
DefaultHttpRequest(chunked: false)
POST /our-product/api/assets/batch-import HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization: Bearer d3173239-3e94-4324-be4b-asdfasw452as
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: NING/1.0
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=JIbZxjblkj0oG0S02OWe47-
Gx_ZlUlNo9Ct
Content-Length: 145758

17:12:36,217 DEBUG ~
Non cached request
DefaultHttpRequest(chunked: false)
POST /our-product/api/assets/batch-import HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization: Bearer d3173239-3e94-4324-be4b-asdfasw452as
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: NING/1.0
Content-Length: 145758

using Channel
[id: 0x00f8dcfe]

17:12:36,260 DEBUG ~

Request DefaultHttpRequest(chunked: false)
POST /our-product/api/assets/batch-import HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization: Bearer d3173239-3e94-4324-be4b-asdfasw452as
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: NING/1.0
Content-Length: 145758

Response DefaultHttpResponse(chunked: false)
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Length: 1424
Server: Jetty(7.4.5.v20110725)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the await-method provided by Play. This methods suspends the controller until the Promise has a result.

```
Promise<HttpResponse> promisedResponse = WS.url("http://service.example.com").postAsync();
HttpResponse actualResponse = await(promisedResponse);
```

Further information and snippets here: [Play! - Asynchronous programming with HTTP](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/asynchronous)